# Was there a dual-core PowerMac G5?

Tags: apple, powerpc, powermac-g5

I have a PowerMac G5 which I have recently succeeded in getting running with a Mac OS X 10.4. I was in for two big surprises: Firstly, the computer runs very fast, even with heavier software like an older version of Photoshop. The second surprise was when I opened the Activity Monitor. It would appear that this computer is either dual-cored or dual-threaded.

Did Apple indeed make dual-core (or dual-thread) PowerMacs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should open the case, or check the "About this Mac" dialog in the Apple menu: there's a fair chance your G5 has two processors, as in two complete packages. All series of G5s were available in dual-socket variants; the very last series of G5s was available with a dual-core processor, resulting in up to four cores in total.

[Wikipedia has the details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Mac_G5#Product_revision_history):

- June 2003 series: single 1.6GHz or 1.8GHz single-core processor, or dual 1.8GHz or 2.0GHz single-core processors;
- June 2004 series: dual 1.8GHz, 2.0GHz or 2.5GHz single-core processors only;
- Late 2004 series: single 1.8GHz single-core processor;
- Early 2005 series: dual 2.0GHz, 2.3GHz or 2.7GHz single-core processors;
- Late 2005 series: single 2.0GHz or 2.3GHz dual-core processor, or dual 2.5GHz dual-core processors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Looks like you probably have it nailed.  I'll look inside it to see if it's got two CPU's.

Comment: There were also aftermarket kits to replace single socket main boards with dual CPU packages.

Comment: Okay, looks like it is truly a dual-core: only one CPU inside.  Thanks again!